# How do you activate the secret ruins?

Tags: chibi-robo-zip-lash

In the first few levels of Chibi-Robo Ziplash, I've seen several ominous brown-colored areas that zoom out the camera.  They clearly house some kind of secrets (as most of them are hidden away from the main path), but I don't seem to have any options when I get there.  Telly said not to worry about them yet, but after fully completing the first world, I still don't know what to do when I see them.  **When and where do you unlock the ability to open secret ruins?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are alien rescue sites.  They are only relevant when **replaying a level after beating it once**.  When you return to a level, there will be a crying alien hidden somewhere in the level nearby one of these sites.  If you grab the alien with your plug and carry it to the site, you can spin it around by holding `Y` which will summon its ship.  If you can lob the alien into the ship, you will have a chance to [unlock an outfit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/239251/96435) or get 50 coins as a consolation prize.